# In Florida, do you need to physically hand over your licence to Police?

Tags: united-states, driving, florida

According to Florida [Statues 322.15](http://www.leg.state.fl.us/statutes/index.cfm?App_mode=Display_Statute&URL=0300-0399/0322/Sections/0322.15.html), It states;

> License to be carried and ***exhibited*** on demand; fingerprint to be
>   imprinted upon a citation.

Does this mean you only need to present the drivers license not hand it over?

Comment: Are you willing to turn and position the license in any and every way the cop might want to look at it?

Comment: From my understanding, you could just hold it to the window and it is considered "exhibited". There is no positional requirement written on law.

Comment: The requirements say "with *no portion* of such license faded, altered, mutilated, or defaced", and the cop is within his rights to verify that those requirements are met. That means if he wants to see the back, for example, you must show the back. If he wants to look at it at a certain angle to ensure any watermark is intact, you must show it at that angle.

Comment: Fair point, so does that mean that given you meet the P.O.'s inspection of the drivers license. That you do not need to hand it over?

Answer (score 1):

Headings are not the statute. The wording there is for information only, and is all but guaranteed to sacrifice nuance for the sake of brevity. The actual requirements are in the contents of the statute.

And subsection (1) states:

> (1) Every licensee shall have his or her driver license...in his or her immediate possession at all times when operating a motor vehicle **and shall present or submit the same upon the demand of a law enforcement officer** or an authorized representative of the department. A licensee may present or submit a digital proof of driver license as provided in s. 322.032 in lieu of a physical driver license.

A police officer is allowed to demand that you *present or submit* your license to him. "Present" and "submit" can both mean "give" in every dictionary i've yet checked. So absent a definition in Florida law, it looks like you have to hand it over.

Comment: Then why have I seen examples during DUI checkpoints here in Florida of individuals _not_ handing over the license but just presenting them? BTW, in one example, the individual was arrested and won the court case regarding obstruction. Here is a youtube if the situation; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=68TlLCbswNw

Comment: Also, the reading of the statue says "OR submit".. which to my understanding is a choice.

Comment: @DigitalFire: Cops aren't usually trying to be hardasses, and they have stuff to do...so unless you've given them reason to suspect you're breaking the law in other ways, they're not always going to press the issue. Plus, a refusal to hand over your license looks like it'd count as a violation of that section, and therefore as a non-criminal traffic infraction. An obstruction charge would be a hell of a leap. As for "OR submit", it's irrelevant. "Present" can mean "give" too.

Comment: Presenting the license without handing it over doesn't mean refusal to ID. And while you may feel it is just easier to comply.Sometime (Like while through a DUI checkpoint) there are moral objections to what is going on from which someone will want to stand by while still observing the law. Which is the bases of this question. I think your interpretation while reasonable, may not be correct.

Comment: "Presenting the license without handing it over" doesn't even exist as an option, if it is specified that "present" means "give".

Comment: That is your opinion. I would like case law that states that. I have shown you an example youtube video and it contains a subsequent case that says otherwise. CASE NUMBER: 16-045 AC - TRIAL CASE NUMBER: A4LAR8E Here is the case http://fairdui.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/fairdui-wins-miami.pdf

Comment: In that document, it appears that the question of whether refusal to hand over a license is a violation, the only time it was ever actually answered, was answered in the affirmative.

Comment: The defendant won the case, in not sure where you get to that conclusion.

Comment: I get to that conclusion by actually reading the whole thing. The reversal was based not on whether the previous judgement was correct, but whether the case should have happened at all because of technical errors. The only case of the three that actually directly addressed your question, found the defendant in violation.

Comment: "Appellant was then charged with a noncriminal traffic violation for
refusal to physically hand over his driver's license to the officer." ..."The hearing officer determined that Redlich was in possession
of a valid driver's license and, over objection of the attorney for Coral Gables, dismissed the
citation."..

Comment: The judge retrialed "found him in violation" then on appeal. Won the case.

Comment: Yeah. In the first case, the hearing officer didn't even bother with the question of whether a violation occurred, because once the validity of the license was confirmed, that court considered the question of violation moot. The second trial actually asked and answered the question. The third asked and answered the question of whether the city was allowed to bring the second trial.

Comment: So the one time the question was asked and answered, it was answered in the affirmative.

Comment: Ok. Then my question is; since the third one invalidated the second. Doesn't that mean that the affirmative answer in the second doesn't even count?

Comment: For the purposes of determining the defendant's guilt or of setting precedent, no, it doesn't count. But what it does do is hint at what would happen when/if the question were brought before a court that wanted to answer it. It also hints at a lack of precedent for your interpretation.

Comment: Here is my last discussion point on this issue; https://youtu.be/to8f_-qWy2U?t=9m30s - 322.15 (2) "Upon the failure of any person to *display*" ..The word display does not mean hand over..

Comment: If you really want to read finely, failure to display in 322.15(2) gives rise to an obligation to provide a finger print, but it doesn't follow that the 322.15(1) requirement to present or submit isn't violated even if you do display and hence don't have to provide a finger print. As cHao aptly notes though, the only time the issue was litigated on the merits, the not hand it over position lost and there are no cases where it won.

Comment: @DigitalFire to the extent that "present or submit" represents a choice, I suspect that it is the officer's choice whether to demand that the license be presented or submitted.  But I agree with cHao that both verbs can mean "give."